# Adding CRS to shapefile in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas, runtimeerror

I am trying to add CRS to a shapefile that I am exporting:

```py
shp1 = gpd.read_file(i[1], encoding='iso8859_7', crs_wkt='2100')
shp1.to_file(out, encoding='iso8859_7', crs_wkt='2100')
```

When I import it to a GIS later, it doesn't have the CRS that says in `crs_wkt`.

I tried to do this:

```py
shp1 = shp1.to_crs(epsg=2100)
```

but says:

```
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

If check for the crs it has

```py
shp1.crs
```

it says:

```py
{}
```

Answer (score 12):

The `to_crs` function is for converting from one CRS to another.
To assign a CRS to a GeoPandas object, simply assign it to the `.crs` attribute.
For example:

```
my_geoseries.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
```

In Geopandas >= 0.7.0, you should use only the EPSG code itself as follows:

```
my_geoseries.crs = 'epsg:4326'
```

The GeoPandas documentation is quite good: http://geopandas.org/projections.html

You trigger the RuntimeError because there is no CRS to convert from, hence the 'no arguments' phrase.

Comment: After giving `crs` the way you suggested it indeed got the `crs` but when i exported it, and opened it in GIS it said that is missing spatial reference information.What is going on?

Comment: @user10092387 save your GeoDataFrame to your shapefile with `to_file('your_file.shp')` if you still have that problem check the .prj file that's where the projection info is, if it's not updated to the desired CRS either change it manually with a valid Proj4 dictionnary or empty it and resave your file using geopandas

Comment: @HichamZouarhi i saved it with to_file but the proj file is empty. Can you tell what exactly to type for the proj4 dictionary to work?

Comment: @user10092387 here is an example of a projection string in a .prj file `PROJCS["RGF93_Lambert_93",GEOGCS["GCS_RGF93",DATUM["D_RGF_1993",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",49],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",44],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],PARAMETER["false_easting",700000],PARAMETER["false_northing",6600000],UNIT["Meter",1]]` you can download a prj file from here  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ggrs87-greek-grid/

Comment: I don't get it. What should i do aside from the `shp1.crs = {'init' :'epsg:2100'}` to actually open it in the GIS with the assigned crs?

Comment: After running `shp1.to_file('shp1.shp')`, go to the directory where you saved the output shapefile and create a .prj file (or download one as Hicham says) and give it the same prefix as your shapefile (shp1.prj in this case)