# geopandas' .crs doesn't store crs on 'proj' file

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

As occurred in this question: [Add CRS to a shapefile in Geopandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289843/add-crs-to-a-shapefile-in-geopandas/289885?noredirect=1)

`f.shp` has not `crs`

This code:

```
 shp=gpd.read_file('f.shp')
 shp.crs = {'init' :'epsg:2100'} 
 out=path
 shp.to_file(out)
```

doesn't store the crs in the proj file and when I open it in `Arcmap` it says that it doesn't have a crs.

Although

```
shp.crs
```

gives

`{'init': 'epsg:2100'}`

How can I make it have the assigned crs when I export it?

I also tried:

```
shp.to_file(out,crs_wkt='2100')
```

so it provides the crs while exporting but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Obviously, I don't have your input file "f.shp", but I just ran your code on a random shapefile at hand, and everything worked. PRJ file was successfully created and had expected contents beginning `PROJCS["GGRS87_Greek_Grid",` etc. Using GeoPandas 0.3.0.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? (and specify which version of geopandas you are using?)