# Saving CRS information using GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas

How does GeoPandas save CRS information?

```py
globe = ccrs.Globe(ellipse='sphere', semimajor_axis=6370000, semiminor_axis=6370000)

crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(globe=globe,central_longitude=111, central_latitude=33,
                            standard_parallels=(30, 60))
crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init

gdf.crs = ccrs.PlateCarree().proj4_init
gdf.to_crs(crs_proj4, inplace=True)
gdf.to_file(r'/Users/sam/Documents/grid_source.shp')
```

and then

```py
a=gpd.read_file(r'/Users/sam/Documents/grid_source.shp').crs
a==gdf.crs
```

returns  `False`.

Comment: can you print the outputs of `gpd.read_file(r'/Users/sam/Documents/grid_source.shp').crs` and `gdf.crs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you do not need the `inplace=True` parameter in your code and also besides re-projecting you also need to set the new crs.

So, the entire code can look like

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

globe = ccrs.Globe(ellipse='sphere', semimajor_axis=6370000, semiminor_axis=6370000)
crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(globe=globe, central_longitude=111, central_latitude=33, standard_parallels=(30, 60))
crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init

gdf = gpd.read_file('P:/Test/qgis_test/grid_test.shp')

gdf.crs = ccrs.PlateCarree().proj4_init
gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_proj4)
gdf.crs = crs_proj4

gdf.to_file('P:/Test/qgis_test/grid_test2.shp')
```

So, after reading the output from the above code

```py
gdf2 = gpd.read_file('P:/Test/qgis_test/grid_test2.shp')
print(gdf2.crs)
```

you may get the following output

```
PROJCS["unknown",GEOGCS["GCS_unknown",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["unknown",6370000,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",33],PARAMETER["central_meridian",111],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

---

**References:**

- [Understanding inplace=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)
- [Adding CRS to shapefile in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289843/add-crs-to-a-shapefile-in-geopandas)
- [GeoPandas Set CRS on Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961816/geopandas-set-crs-on-points)
- [GeoPandas Docs | Managing Projections](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html#managing-projections)

Comment: Small comment on your code: it is currently not keeping the reprojected data. You need to re-assign it: `gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_proj4)` (and not set the crs afterwards)

Comment: Please feel free to adjust it 

Comment: `gdf.to_crs(crs_proj4, inplace=True)` may means `gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_proj4)`, and Thanks for helping! It did't influece my own work but I need to exchange someting with my co-workers.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)