# GeoPandas does not write CRS in MapInfo Tab

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, mapinfo

I'm trying to convert a GeoTIFF file into a MapInfo format with Python and GeoPandas. To do that, I'm using the following code:

```py
mask = None
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open('geoTiff.tif') as src:
        image = src.read(1)
        result = ({'properties': {'rasterVal': v}, 'geometry': s}
        for i, (s,v) in enumerate(shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))

geoms = list(result)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms, crs='EPSG:21781')
gdf = gdf[gdf['rasterVal'] == 1]
gdf = gdf.to_crs(21781)
```

At this point, when I print `gdf.crs` I get the correct CRS

But if I export the gdf (`gdf.to_file("test2.tab", driver='MapInfo File')`) and then reload it (`g = geopandas.read_file('test2.tab')`) I get the following CRS:

```
<Projected CRS: PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["WGS_1984" ...>
Name: unnamed
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- [east]: Easting (metre)
- [north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: unnamed
- method: Hotine Oblique Mercator (variant B)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

The problem is that when I try to open it in MapInfo I have a difference of 75m in X and 150m in Y with the original GeoTIFF file.

[image]

How can I change my code to correct this problem?

Comment: IMHO, you are missing this piece `gdf.crs = "EPSG:21781"` just after `gdf = gdf.to_crs(21781)` . Maybe this can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416112/saving-crs-information-using-geopandas/416136#416136. Can you try it again?

Comment: It doesn't change the result when I do that. I also tried with a shp file instead of the map info and when I read it the CRS is inside. So it seems to be only with the MapInfo export

Comment: What is `shapes()` ? From where do you import this module? Is it `from rasterio.features import shapes` or `from rasterio.rio.shapes import shapes`?

Comment: Yes it's a rasterio feature (from rasterio.features import shapes)

Comment: Have a look at the .tab file, it is plain text. What mapinfo projection does it report?

Comment: There is no information about the projection in the TAB file

Comment: Ok, MapInfo does not store that into TAB in case of GeoTIFF "A fully registered image, containing control points and a projection (for example, GeoTIFF file)."

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. I'm not using a tab file combined with a GeoTIFF, it's a conversion of a GeoTIFF to polygon and exported as a MapInfo file